# 'altro' vs. 'altri'

Tags: pronouns, agreement

Just found this tweet:

> '500 MILIONI FONDO PER LE IMPRESE SOCIALI' sono regalo per 'terzo settore', che *altro* non è che serbatoio elettorale e clientelare.

Is *altro* correct? Or, maybe, should it be *altri*?

Thank you.

Comment: These are indefinite pronouns: "altro" is for things or concepts («cinquecento milioni non sono altro che spiccioli», «[bugiarda che non sei altro!](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/altro2/)»); "altri" is for people («Tizia altri non è che la cugina di Caio», «[Venite a noi parlar, s’altri nol niega!](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/altri/)»). Note how, in modern Italian, "altro" is usually invariant with respect to (not concordant with) the number and gender of the associated noun or name.

Answer (score 5):

'Non essere altro che...' is an idiom that means 'To be nothing but...'.

Example: **Lui** (*singular*) non **è** (*singular*) altro che uno scocciatore. = He's nothing but a nuisance.

In this idiom, 'altro' (indefinite pronoun) is generally never used in the plural form, but the verb can be (depending on the number of the subject):

Example: **Loro** (*plural*) non **sono** (*plural*) altro che degli scocciatori. = They're nothing but a nuisance.

Note how the verb *to be* always agrees with the subject.

Comment: I think the subject is "terzo settore", in this case it's concordant. I agree with the general reasoning.

Comment: @laika is right, it's the "terzo settore" that is "serbatoio elettorale e clientelare", not "500 milioni" (nor "regalo"). The _è_ is correct, _sono_ would be wrong.

Comment: Deleted the part that stated that "500 milioni" was the subject.

Comment: OK, sorry for the rollback.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by kYuZz and donnadulcinea, these are indefinite pronouns: "altro" is for things or concepts («cinquecento milioni non sono altro che spiccioli», «[bugiarda che non sei altro!](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/altro2/)»); "altri" is for people («Tizia altri non è che la cugina di Caio», «[Venite a noi parlar, s’altri nol niega!](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/altri/)»).

Note how, in modern Italian, "altro" and "altri" are usually not concordant with (invariant with respect to) number and gender of the subject. Not so in the past. Consider for example Giovanni Boccaccio in his *Decameron* (1), Galileo Galilei in his *Dialogo sopra i due massimi sistemi del mondo* (2) or Giacomo Leopardi, in his *Zibaldone* (3, 4):

1. «Padre mio, le novelle che io ho [non sono altre che](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/b/boccaccio/decameron_branca/pdf/boccaccio_decameron_branca.pdf) di quello maladetto da Dio vostro amico»;
2. «Che poi al moto circolare niuno altro sia contrario, lo prova Aristotile in molte maniere; ma senza replicarle tutte, assai apertamente resta dimostrato, mentre che i moti semplici [non sono altri che tre](http://www.letteraturaitaliana.net/pdf/Volume_6/t333.pdf), al mezo, dal mezo e intorno al mezo, de i quali i dua retti sursum et deorsum sono manifestamente contrari, e perché un solo ha un solo per contrario, adunque non resta altro movimento che possa esser contrario al circolare»;
3. «La causa di questa differenza, [non è altra che](http://www.classicitaliani.it/leopardi/zibaldone/leopardi_zibaldone_1915_2194.htm) la mancanza di assuefazioni determinanti e creanti l'armonia o disarmonia de' colori puri»;
4. «E quantunque anche la disinvoltura possa essere affettata, e da ciò guasta, tuttavia possiamo dire iperbolicamente, che se veruna affettazione è permessa allo scrittore, [non è altra che](http://www.leopardi.it/zibaldone2.php) questa di non accorgersi nè prevedere i begli effetti che le sue parole faranno in chi leggerà, o ascolterà, e di non aver volontà nè scopo nessuno, eccetto quello ch’è manifesto e naturale, di narrare, di celebrare, compiangere ec.».

This use is still possible in modern Italian, it sounds archaic though.